# Animate Element and make it drag&droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a game, where a few products are flying one after another from right to left. The whole time they should also be draggable and be dropped to a certain position. But while dragged, they should not be animated, of course.

The code I have so far, animates the element, while dragging:

```
var animateElement = function(currentIndex) {
        var endpoint = 20000;
        $('.product-' + currentIndex.toString()).draggable();
        $('.product-' + currentIndex.toString()).transition({
                x: -600,
                y: 100,
            }, endpoint, "linear",
            function() {
                stopAnimation(currentIndex);
            }
        ); //END ANIMATION

        $('#dropProducthere').droppable({
            accept: '.product-' + currentIndex.toString()
        }); //END droppable
    }

    var stopAnimation = function(currentIndex) {
        $('.product-' + currentIndex.toString()).stop().transition();
    }
```

Is there a better solution than my one above?

Comment: This is not good that your product fly right to left, It is not true in ui/ux design

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Well, it actually is a game and makes perfect sense.

Comment: And I already know about the stop at transitions, as you can see in my code.

Comment: you should this .stop()